# How to download data from mysql database and store it into local database for offline using in android?

Tags: android, mysql, database, download, offline

Actually I want to download all data from mysql database and want to store it into my local sqlite database in android. I want to show some data of my mysql database into listview when user don't have internet connection or any internet failure. I am getting images and text data into my listview when I have internet but in the same time I want to build one button like click this button to store data offline if user click that button then all data would be download and store into my local database and then it will show separately offline listview. Please guide me thanks
I don't know how to download data using apis and store into my local database In android...!
Anyone Who can help me Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you are showing the data from the mysql database it means, you are using some sort of APIs to show the data. To store the data offline, it will be a nice idea to parse the API data to some POJO classes and bind those classes with Realm objects. Using realm you can store the data in offline mode without implementing SQLite or any kind of local database options. Please let me know if you need to know anything in details.

POJO Class as per your JSON:

```
public class LocationObject extends RealmObject {
    String locations;
    String brands;
    String discounts;

    public LocationObject(String locations, String brands, String discounts) {
        this.locations = locations;
        this.brands = brands;
        this.discounts = discounts;
    }

    public String getLocations() {
        return locations;
    }

    public void setLocations(String locations) {
        this.locations = locations;
    }

    public String getBrands() {
        return brands;
    }

    public void setBrands(String brands) {
        this.brands = brands;
    }

    public String getDiscounts() {
        return discounts;
    }

    public void setDiscounts(String discounts) {
        this.discounts = discounts;
    }
}

public class LocationList extends RealmList<LocationObject> {
}

public class LocationPojo {
    LocationList Loc_result;

    public LocationList getLoc_result() {
        return Loc_result;
    }

    public void setLoc_result(LocationList loc_result) {
        Loc_result = loc_result;
    }

}
```

Finally integrating Realm into your project, please check [this](https://realm.io/docs/get-started/android-demo-app/)

Comment: Thanks  a lot. Could you explain in details for me. I will be owe to you

Comment: Yes sure. Can you please show me some of your API responses ? It will help me to design the POJO classes

Comment: This is my api result which I am getting in jason form <br>{"Loc_result":[{"locations":"Shop 4,Block 12D, F-7 Markaz, Islamabad","brands":"#Eat","discounts":"15"},{"locations":"F-11 Markaz, Islamabad","brands":"160 degrees","discounts":"15"},{"locations":"Pakistan Sports Complex, Islamabad.","brands":"Allied Badminton Academy","discounts":"20"}]}